# Asimptotic Inequality of two expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

$$\left(\log \left(\log \:\left(n\right)\right)\right)^n\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\prod _{k=2}^n\left(\log \:k\right)\:$$

Hi, I need to measure the asymptotic quantity of both expressions each by itself and their quantity each to other (which is bigger).

I tried induction, but it's didn't work for me. 
I can also try to bound the right $\:\:\:\:\:\log \:\:n\le \prod _{k=2}^n\left(\log \:k\right)\le \left(\log \:\:n\right)^n$ but it is too rude and doesn't help me a lot.

One more thought that came to me right now is to take the right expression, it's k from particular point, for example k = 9, and than I'll get an exponential growth of $$3^n$$ with some coefficient. 
So it is very big, I assume, bigger then $2^n$ or $3^n$ asymptotically, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The key fact to observe is that

$$(\log \log n)^n < (\log n)^{\frac{1}{2}n}$$

which is true because $\log \log n < \log^{\frac12} n$. Then, just check that

$$\sum_{k=n/3}^n\log\log k \geq \frac{2}{3}n\log\log\frac{n}{3} \geq \frac12 n \log \log n$$

for sufficiently large $n$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$